# Joomla 3.x shows a blank home page with only the menu and login form with no content

Tags: joomla

I'm following a tutorial on how to build a website with joomla 3.1, the installation was successful but the default homepage template shows a blank page with only title and login form. there are no menu, articles, and other contents.

I have repeated the installation process several times but I still get the same result.

Comment: please i am a beginner and i would appreciate if any one here can help me solve this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a URL to see the output?

Comment: @RiaanV the URL works fine as it loads the site, but the front page is not complete

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Is it on your localhost or on a live server that the problem is ocurring on?

Comment: Okay and does it give the same result when you upload to a live server?

Comment: no have not tried uploading to a live server, as i am just starting to learn web design. i am using a wamp server and i have uninstall and reinstall the server as well but the problem persist

Comment: everything work fine except that the front page of my site looks diffrent from the one present in the tutorial am using

Comment: The problem will then be with your localhost setup please check out this tutorial. hope that this helps mate. http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-mar-2013/item/1110-free-e-book-%E2%80%93-introducing-joomla-30-made-easy

Comment: I suggest trying an alternative template. Adding a screen capture of the default home page to your question might help.

Comment: @Neil Robertson that's is exactly what i have been trying to do but i don't know how to go about it. i capture the screen but i couldn't put it here. please teach me how. thanks

Comment: To add an image, edit your question, click on the image icon, drag an image into the pop-up window and click on the "Add Picture" button.

Comment: to to every body for contributions, i never knew joomla had several other templates cause it wasn't specify in the tutorial i was following, i also discover that the tutorial was using joomla 2xx which is a bit obsolete. the link from provided by @ RiaanV was a great eye opener.

Comment: i would also appreciate if some one can help me with a good and comprehensive joomla tutorial, that will help me learn how to use joomla to build good websites. my aim is to build a standard bulk sms webiste. thanks